# Access git tag message in Travis build

Tags: git, travis-ci

I have a git project set up for build and deployment with Travis CI. The actual deployment is configured to only happen on tags, this way I trigger a deployment by creating a release tag.

When I give the deployment a name and description (for Elastic Beanstalk, which is where it gets deployed to) I would like to use the tag message as the description.

**I can't figure out how to get the tag message, if that's even possible(?).** `TRAVIS_TAG` has the name of the tag and is used as the name of the deploy, but the description gets defaulted to the latest commit message.
This is not what I want to describe the release. I want the release title, which happens to be the tag message, to describe the release.

The latest commit message is available in `TRAVIS_COMMIT_MESSAGE` but unfortunately there's no `TRAVIS_TAG_MESSAGE` or anything like that.

**Is it possible to get the tag message in the Travis build process?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the tag message by doing one of the following - either using `TRAVIS_TAG` or getting the tag associated with `HEAD`:

```
git tag -ln --format '%(subject)' $TRAVIS_TAG

git tag -ln --format '%(subject)' $(git describe --exact-match HEAD)
```

Comment: Excellent! Works perfectly. Unfortunately, I was mistaken when I thought the tag message was the same as the release title. Turns out the tag message is just the last commit message, so I need to figure something else out :p

Comment: It should be the tag message if you use annotated tags with  `git tag -a`

Comment: The thing is that I don't create the tag manually, it's created automatically as a lightweight tag when I publish a release in GitHub.

Comment: Ahh yes, I've hit that before. I believe that you can first push an annotated tag from the command line, and then select this tag from the github web page where you create releases - that might not suit your workflow though...

Comment: Right, that would make my release process a bit less simple and straightforward than I'd like. Also, the tag message and release title in GitHub are still two different things. I guess it makes sense, considering releases are GitHub's proprietary thing. I might solve it using GitHub's REST API to retrieve the release title, but at the end of the day it's probably not worth the effort.